# Bootstrap jumbotron width issue on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, responsive

I have an issue with my jumbotron which contains some text and a button. Basically on a small screen (320) the text contained in it doesn't diaplay centered anymore and a white sidebar appears on the right and I can't figure out where that is coming from. You can see it in the 240 and 320 screen here: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ the website is http://test.assatena.it/

html

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center container-fluid center-block">
    <div class="container center-block">
        <h1 class="center-block">Associazione Culturale e Musicale Atena</h1>
        <div class="text-center center-block"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-iscrizione" class="page-scroll btn btn-success btn-xl">iscriviti qui!</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://www.assatena.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/sfondo1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: The extra space you are getting is not because of your Jumbotron, it's because of the img elements without "max-width:100%".  Talking about your "News" Section. Also lower your font-size for small screen. That will solve your issue about centering text.

Comment: Try to change the font size for that screen width, using media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img{max-width:100%;}
.jumbotron h1 {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Comment: just add this css then after u cant see scroll on smaller then 320px